# MSIE: Append XML Element to HTML Element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using an XMLHttpRequest to retrieve XML from the server, and I'd like to append it to an existing HTML node on the page. It's well formed HTML and I've added `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'` to the XML root element in the response: works fine for Firefox, but IE bombs with "No such interface supported", I guess because it's got the node I'm trying to append typed as "IXMLDOMElement".

Here's the XML response:

```xml
<qstat xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Cycle number:</b> 6</li>
        <li><b>Error:</b> none</li>
    </ul>
</qstat>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(req.readyState == 4)
    {
        dom = req.responseXML;
        var nodes = dom.firstChild.childNodes;   //Everything under the root node.
        var ele = document.getElementById("qstat");
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
        {
            ele.appendChild(nodes[i]);  // BOMBS HERE.
        }
    }
};
```

The MSIE Debugger (MSIE 8) correctly identifies `nodes[0]` as having `tagName=ul` and even has `namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, but I guess because it's type is `IXMLDOMElement`, the call doesn't work.

So is there any way to convert the objects in `nodes` to corresponding HTML node objects that I can append to the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

1) create an HTML element

```
var factory = document.createElement("div");
```

2) serialize the fetch XML element

```
var xml = nodes[i].xml || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(nodes[i]);
```

3) render xml through innerHTML

```
factory.innerHTML = xml;
```

4) get firstChild from factory element which is now HTML element

```
var eleHTML = factory.firstChild;
```

5) append eleHTML to where you need it:

```
ele.appendChild(eleHTML);
```

Hint: you can reuse once created factory DOMHTML element

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm not sure why I need the factory element though? I've I'm resorting to `innerHTML`, why not just go directly to `ele.innerHTML = xml`?

Comment: You can do this too. I tried to answer your question "MSIE: Append XML Element to HTML Element"